# Whenever I try to run the code I get the error: expression expected

Tags: excel, vba

I built an Excel chess game, and wanted to record the moves made by the players through events. This is the code I have:

```
Dim isRunning As Boolean
Dim moves As New Collection

Sub start_button_Click()
    isRunning = True
End Sub

Sub stop_button_Click()
    isRunning = False
    Dim val As Variant

    For Each val In moves
        Debug.Print val
    Next val

    Set moves = Nothing
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If isRunning Then
        moves.Add Target.Address & " " & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

For some reason whenever I run the start method or the stop method I get the error:

> "Expected: expression"

without it highlighting any line of the code, and sometimes when I run the stop method it gives an error and highlights the line `For Each val In moves` in the claim that it is empty.

The code works on a blank/new Excel file but not on my chess program.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. If I copy the complete code into the scope of a worksheet I can run it without the issues you describe.

Answer (score 3):

Once this happens in the "stop" method:

```
Set moves = Nothing
```

then you can no longer call `moves.Add` without first assigning a new collection to `moves`

Try this change:

```
Sub start_button_Click()
    Set moves = New Collection
    isRunning = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You are right I missed that, but unfortunately it didn't fix the problem...

Comment: @TimWilliams actually that is exactly what I would have expected. But if `moves` is `Nothing` then `moves.Add` just initiates a new `Collection` automatically on its first call. I assume this is because the variable is declared `As New Collection` and not just `As Collection`.